# How does Bane's crew know where to dig?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight-rises

In the movie:

> Bane's crew is working in the tunnels and sewers of Gotham. One of their goals is to burrow under Wayne Tower and get into Bruce's personal armory.

But this made me wonder, how does Bane know the exact location of

> Bruce's Armory.

It's stated in the movie that

> His armory is locked up tight and only he and Fox know about it's existence. As far as we know, not even Natalia knows its location.

So how did Bane know?

Answer (score 8):

The movie drops a lot of hints. Talia was working within Wayne Enterprises for years, and Bane had Daggett's construction crews working all over the city for months.

It's never mentioned, but must be assumed that Wayne Tower was under surveillance by the League of Shadows. Talia and Bane's plan had been in operation for years (like the slow knife) before the movie even begins.

Nolan movies force the viewer to fill in the blanks.

Answer (score 6):

He was provided the information by Wayne Industries insider Daggett, presumably.

Comment: I don't buy that... How did Daggett know about the armory? Again, according to the movie only Wayne and Fox it's existance and location. There is no evidence to support Daggett knowing it's location.

Comment: If you accept that only Wayne and Fox knew about it, then Fox must have told Bane, which seems silly. So, somebody else had to know about it, someone who was connected with Bane...Daggett. Fox THOUGHT no one else knew about it, but he was wrong.

Comment: We know from Dark Knight that at least one fellow, Mr. Reese, had sniffed around it before.

Comment: If Mr. Reese where somehow an informant for Bane then I might buy that... But it felt like Daggett was lower on "totem pole", they mention in the movie that Daggett is actually head of a company hoping to buy out Wayne Industries. So I don't see how he would get the information about the Armory.

Comment: Well, I kind of chalked it up to Fox having had good intentions, but counter-espionage wasn't his field, and he was certainly no match for a determined espionage organization. I think you can kind of piece it together like this: 1. Bane knows from his association with the League of Shadows about Batman / Wayne. 2. Batman has some serious firepower. 3. I wonder what else Wayne has tucked away? 4. Let's get some people inside / around Wayne Industries to find out.

Comment: You make some good points, but this doesn't mean that Daggett was the informant. If anything I feel like Daggett was kept in the dark about most of what Bane's crew knew and was planning, since he was just a pawn in the overall scheme of things. Daggett had one goal, and that was to take control of Wayne Industries, not to destroy Gotham.

Comment: Unless Fox and Wayne dug it and poured the concrete themselves, someone else knew of the building. Even if they purchased something built prior and repurposed it, that'll show up in the bookkeeping somewhere.

Comment: I don't believe they said that Fox and Wayne were the only ones who "knew" about the armory.  What he said was that it was locked up tight and off the books.  That's different than no one else knowing about its existence.

Comment: Perhaps it started with an insider, blueprints to the facility, and curiosity about an enormous blank space in those blueprints.

Answer (score 5):

I figure that the criminal mastermind Bane looks for the *source* of Batman's firepower, deciding to look for a building with floors strong enough to handle a bevy of tanks.  With the aid of DWB and Dagget Industry records and crews, Bane found the proper infrastructure, and deduced that it was the spot.

Remember, Bane isn't just *Physically* a match for Batman-- by that logic, the most dangerous Batman villain should be Killer Croc-- but also mentally.  He's basically the only villain with the ability to use a single phrase to justify plot holes.  Instead of "Because he's Batman" its "Because he's Bane."

If the Kid from 3rd Rock can figure out Batman's identity, I'm sure Bane could find the guy's garage.

Answer (score 2):

I assumed that they found out once Talia took control of Wayne Enterprises. She became privy to the fusion reactor, so why not the armory too.

Comment: That was my first thought, but I don't think the timing is right. I think they had to be digging before that.

Comment: She became privy to the fusion reactor after it was shown to her. And it's stored in a different place then the armory. She was never told about the armory, so unless she somehow hacked into a database looking specifically for it she wouldn't even have known of it's existence.

Comment: @onewho I was thinking more along the lines of she got all the info when she became the top dog at Wayne Enterprises. I figured that's why Daggett wanted to become the head honcho, so he could find out where all the secrets were buried.

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens That was also my surmise, but to me, it's the only logical solution. Short of the Riddler's mind reader :)

Comment: This is a master spy organization, not just assassins. It could have been more simpler than 'hacking the systems' but checking security cams of fox's office and the like. But I do think it came from talia and I don't think they dug that area out as much as that was there already.  Most of the work was them laying new cement and ground work, reinforcing existing structures. I don't remember seeing any dirt hauling.

Comment: @Mike Ramirez: If you refined that into an answer and backed it up with even a little bit of evidence I'd actually accept that as "the answer".

Comment: @onewho that's the problem, don't have evidence other than simple speculation based on the movie and usual things. Mostly also, I'm just speaking on the existing comments, not trying to answer. If anyone else wants to take onewho up on his offer go for it.

Comment: I doubt Talia found out about the armory from becoming CEO, especially since Fox made it very clear to Wayne that the armory was completely off the books.